# DequeReusableAnnotationView crashing program

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, mapkit

Im writing a program in IOS where i mark a few spots on the map with a pin. 
Now i have the dequereusableannotationview code that works fine with ONE pin but crashes with i use two pins or try to mark two points on the map.
IT only works when i either comment out ONE annotation or comment out the dequeucode
But the question is....do i even need that dequeue code? as the most pins i will ever have is probably...10..?

Thanks you

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MKMapView *mv=[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    mv.delegate=self;
    [self setView:mv];

    MapAnnotation* ann=[[MapAnnotation alloc]init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude=(double)51.501468;
    location.longitude=(double)-0.141596;
    [ann setCoordinate:location];
    [ann setTitle:@"test"];
    [ann setTitle:@"plz work"];
    [mv addAnnotation:ann];
    [ann release];

    MapAnnotation* AnnB=[[MapAnnotation alloc]init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D locationB;
    locationB.latitude=(double)16.4944;
    locationB.longitude=(double)-151.7364;
    [AnnB setCoordinate:locationB];
    [AnnB setTitle:@"test"];
    [AnnB setSubtitle:@"work"];

    [mv addAnnotation:AnnB];
    [AnnB release];
}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView=nil;

    if (annotation!=mapView.userLocation) {
        static NSString *defaultID=@"MYLoction";

        pinView=(MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView
                                        dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultID];
        if (pinView=nil) {
            pinView=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultID]autorelease];

            pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
            pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
            pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that when you test for equality in

```
if (pinView=nil) {
```

you are using the assignment operator, `=`, instead of the equality operator, `==`. This will cause `nil` to be assigned to `pinView` every time, so you will never reuse an annotation. I'm surprised the compiler didn't catch this.

Also, you aren't actually returning anything in `viewForAnnotation:`. Try this instead:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:
    (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if(annotation == mapView.userLocation) {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *defaultID=@"MYLoction";

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView 
        dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultID];

    if (!pinView) {
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
            reuseIdentifier:defaultID] autorelease];

        pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
    }

    return pinView;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks it worked perfectly...but one more question.
Can you do .span with annotations? Im reffering to the blue pulse that the location marker does. I believe the property is span but when i try to do ann.span i dont see it.

Comment: No. I'm not aware of any way to change the radius of the blue pulse

Comment: hmmm ok, so that 'pulse' is it reserved for your location?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm not sure replicating it would be a good idea even if it were possible. The standard way the map views work is the pulse represents the user's location; using it in any other way would be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with proper changes.  Following code works for me.

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation {

  static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MNMyLocation class]]) {

  ```
  MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [atmLocatorMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
  if (annotationView == nil) {
      annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
  } else {
      annotationView.annotation = annotation;
  }

  annotationView.enabled = YES;
  annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
  //annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrest.png"];

  return annotationView;
  ```

  }

  return nil;

}
`